# Travis-CI environment variables & deployment files

Tags: github, deployment, continuous-integration, yaml, travis-ci

I have a small question that hopefully can get a quick answer. For Travis-CI repos set up for a C language project, are the variables defined in a `./configure` script exported to travis build environment / subsystem? I just want to know if I can do the following with my `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  # ...
  file:
    - distribution-$VERSION.tar.gz
    - distribution-$VERSION.zip
    - distribution-windows-$VERSION.zip
```

Comment: If the `./configure` script uses, say, `export VERSION=asdf`, then yes. Try it.

Comment: It sadly does not. :( The `./configure` script provides `VERSION` as a static value in the script. If there's no way to dynamically provide the variable, I guess I can make do with managing it myself. I'm trying to make [abcm2ps](http://moinejf.free.fr/) to automate github release deployments, but the project doesn't use auto tools anymore or have a way to communicate it's script variables to anything outside its environment. The only other option is its `build.ninja` file, which... Travis-CI has no support for. (´●▽● `) Can the file attributes in .travis.yml use wildcards?